# Firebase not connecting completely with two modules in project where one is library module

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-library, android-module

I have imported sevral libraries in my app.One of them works only when a separate module is created in the project folder.Finally after connecting to firebase ,it doesn't connects completely.In firebase pane (In Android Studio) it shows: **1 of 2 modules are Connected**.
Because of this I cannot access the Database/Storage-Rules in the firebase.What is the correct procedure to fully connect my project?

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect library modules to Firebase.  You only connect application modules.  Firebase integrates into application modules by adding a google-services.json file along with a gradle plugin in the app's build.gradle.

If you are having a specific problem running your app after integration, post that question instead.